# ADF Expression @and?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am having issues with the following ADF Expression in my Filter Activity.

and(@contains(createArray('BCO','BED','BSC','BNB'),item().company), equals(item().classcode,'EMP'))

I am getting the following warning: Warning
Expression of type: 'String' does not match the field: 'condition'

Can anyone assist?
THanks
Mike

Comment: Per my experience, the expression should like this: `@and(contains(createArray('BCO','BED','BSC','BNB'),item().company), equals(item().classcode,'EMP'))`. Please try it again.

Comment: Hi @Mike, can you please check again for me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Like the error said the first `and` condition `@contains(createArray('BCO','BED','BSC','BNB'),item().company` isn't a condition expression and doesn't return a true or false, It's s Sting.

Your filter expression should like this:

```
@and(contains(createArray('BCO','BED','BSC','BNB'),item().company), equals(item().classcode,'EMP'))
```

Ref: [and](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#and).

HTH.